How to initialize a react-native app of version 0.75.2 in year 2024?
I am trying to create a react-native app with latest version (0.75.2). I created the project with  npx @react-native-community/cli init newapp. Then I start the project with yarn start command. Then when I type yarn android, it downloads gradle 8.8 as written in gradle properties (distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.8-all.zip). Then the ERROR comes.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\react\newapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']
> java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\react\newapp\android\.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-d380c3b5-5c8f-4497-a8a6-a9f1675d5c36) to immutable location (C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\react\newapp\android\.gradle\8.8\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10) 

I tried many times, I ran npx react-native doctor but no luck and result:
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Metro - Required for bundling the JavaScript code

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 34.0.0

Note: I was using react-native of version 0.69 without any error.
react-native info output:
System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
  CPU: (12) x64 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1255U
  Memory: 16.19 GB / 31.75 GB
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.10.0
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  Yarn:
    version: 3.6.4
    path: ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
  npm:
    version: 10.2.3
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
  Android SDK: Not Found
  Windows SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: AI-231.9392.1.2311.11255304
  Visual Studio: Not Found
Languages:
  Java: 17.0.9
  Ruby: Not Found
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.3.1
    wanted: 18.3.1
  react-native:
    installed: 0.75.2
    wanted: 0.75.2
  react-native-windows: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found

Gradle version output is:
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.8
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2024-05-31 21:46:56 UTC
Revision:     4bd1b3d3fc3f31db5a26eecb416a165b8cc36082

Kotlin:       1.9.22
Groovy:       3.0.21
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.9 (Microsoft 17.0.9+8-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

EDIT: I downgraded gradle to 8.5 as suggested on answers in this forum, but again no luck. gradlew clean also doesn't work with the same error stated.

Maybe just give it a try and install Android SDK 34.0.0 since thats a missing piece in your setup! And be sure to add it to your $PATH.

It exitsts, as I said I could start any project with react native 0.69. Also 0.73. echo %path% result:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.9.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet;

C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\JOHN.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.9.8-hotspot\bin;

Maybe check if the locations are correct, also set your JAVA_SDK env var
